# How to position DataTables buttons outside of table wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Can you please take a look at **[This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/gz586wpj/)** and let me know how I can re-position the dataTabes buttons somewhere else , let say inside `.panel-heading` calss and apply `btn-sm` to them?

Here is the very basic standard format which I have now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
         responsive: true,
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'csv']
    });
});
```

and as you are fully aware it is adding the buttons inside `#example-wrapper`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.  Use jQuery `appendTo()`, like this:

```
//create DataTable first, then...
$("#example_wrapper > .dt-buttons").appendTo("div.panel-heading");
```

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gz586wpj/1/

There's also a `prependTo()` that you can consider.

Comment: Thanks Marc,   I thinks foe `btn-sm` I need to add the classes into each buttons separately?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would look at how you're currently creating the buttons.  Get them to a point where you like them, then inspect them with your browser tools.  They're not `button` elements (it's a combination of anchor tags and spans), so I'm not sure which element actually needs the style.  When you figure it out, just use `$(your_element).addClass("btn-sm");` to style that element.